# How to obtain data property from MatSnackBarConfig

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I've read in the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api), that `MatSnackBarConfig` object could have a `data` property which represents

> Data being injected into the child component.

So I guess  I can use those data inside a custom snack-bar opened via `openFromComponent` method. The question is can I do that? If yes, then how can I do that?

Having [an example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/mjolryoarpy) provided in the documentation, let's say I modify the `openSnackBar` method to the following:

**app/snack-bar-component-example.ts**

```
openSnackBar() {
  this.snackBar.openFromComponent(PizzaPartyComponent, {
    duration: 500, data: {message: 'Hello World!'}
  });
}
```

Now, how could I obtain the `data` object within the `PizzaPartyComponent`?
I've tried to inject it to the component's constructor but it couldn't be resolved.

```
//below code results in error

export class PizzaPartyComponent {
  constructor(private data: any) { 
    console.log(data); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found the solution on material's [github page](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/5.1.x/src/lib/snack-bar/snack-bar.md#sharing-data-with-a-custom-snack-bar).

It turned out that I had injected the data in a wrong manner. The proper one was:

```
import {MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA} from '@angular/material';

// @Component decorator omitted
export class PizzaPartyComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any) { }
}
```